# How to store an audio to db/s3bucket that is streamed to my spring boot application/listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, audio-streaming, audio-recording, data-storage

I have a spring boot application with redis pub/sub. An audio is streamed to my application in 300ms chunks for processing. How can I store the whole audio to db or s3 bucket and remain stateless as well? AUdio is streamed with other information like sessionid and capture time. I want to accumulate the whole audio and save it either to db or s3 bucket. Is AWS Kinesis helpful in this scenario?

I have listeners setup that reads 300 ms chunks of this audio. I want to store the whole audio to database or s3 bucket.

Comment: I am using s3 multipart api to collect data in 5 MB chinks and upload them as part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using s3 multipart api to collect data in 5 MB chunks and upload them as part.
Kinesis is helpful to store the audio data as soon as it comes in. You can then read the data and start s3 multipart upload.